# How to get the path string for D3 Axis

Tags: d3.js

Is there an efficient way to get the path string of an axis generated in D3 from an axis generator function e.g. below as I need to get the intersection of a path added to the chart later on that bisects the X axis,

```
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,10]).range([0,width]);

var xAxis = g.append("g")
.attr("class","x-axis-right")
.attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
.style("fill","blue")
.style("stroke","none")

var xAxisCall = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

xAxis.transition(t).call(xAxisCall);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the path string of an axis"?

Comment: as in the "d" attribute thta is the svg string of the path thta draws the axis

Answer (score 1):

It makes little sense to me why would you want the `d` attribute, but anyway, this is how to do it:

In D3, *getters* are pretty much methods without the second argument. So, if this sets the `d` attribute...

```
selection.attr("d", foo);
```

... this gets it:

```
selection.attr("d");
```

Therefore, all you need is to select the desired path, which in your case would be:

```
xAxis.select("path").attr("d");
```

Here is the demo, look at the console:

```js
var width = 500,
  height = 100;
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 10]).range([10, width - 10]);

var xAxis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x-axis-right")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height - 30})`)
  .style("fill", "blue")
  .style("stroke", "none")

var xAxisCall = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

xAxis.call(xAxisCall);

var pathString = xAxis.select("path").attr("d");

console.log(pathString)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```